# Inflating a pop up window / width of list view and text view

Tags: android, textview, popup, width, popupwindow

I have a pop up window that inflates a list view in a relative layout and a list view that inflates a text view in a relative layout. The width of the pop up window defaults to match parent eventhough I have defined everywhere wrap content, both in layout files and programmatically, only.

I am looking to have a width of pop up window to wrap the content of the text views inside the list view by taking the width of the largest text view and then align all text to the left, either in bold typeface with white background (unread messages) and normal typeface in grey background (read messages).

The width of longest text, say, 'Raspberry (8:11 PM)' in bold typeface is 203. I am trying to assign it by using `popupWindow.setWidth(maximum_width)` after the pop up window is created, programmatically.

(Some lines that are not specific enough to this asked question have been removed).

```
// int maximum_height = 0;
int maximum_width = 0;

public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewgroup) {
    ...
//  if(height > maximum_height)
//      {
//          maximum_height = height;
//      }

    if(width > maximum_width)
        {
            maximum_width = width;
        }
    ...
}
```

The following functions of `textView1.getHeight()` and `textView1.getWidth()` always return 0. Why?

So, based upon some suggestions in Stack Overflow, I have tried with in the following of alternative ways and methods:

```
textView1.measure(0, 0);
int width = textView1.getMeasuredWidth();
```

This returns 0 for the first time, 180 for the second time and 195 from then onwards.

During first time, whenever a width of 0 is returned for the text view in a list view, and then I am also getting within the following warning message too. Why?

W/InputEventReceiver: Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.

By making use of this piece of code:

```
Rect bounds = new Rect();
Paint textPaint = textView1.getPaint();

textPaint.getTextBounds(name, 0, name.length(), bounds);
int width = bounds.width();
```

it returns 0 for the first time and 195 from then onwards.

Also, why does:

```
switch(read)
    {
        case 0:
            textPaint.setTypeface(Typeface.BOLD);
            break;
        case 1:
            textPaint.setTypeface(Typeface.NORMAL);
            break;
    }
```

give an error message of stating that setTypeface(android.graphics.Typeface) cannot be applied to (int)? Is there any way that anyone over here by knows that it can be resolved up with in?

By making use of this piece of code:

```
Rect bounds = new Rect();
Paint textPaint = textView1.getPaint();

textPaint.measureText(name, 0, name.length());
int width = bounds.width();
```

it always returns 0.

By making use of this piece of code:

```
TextPaint paint = new TextPaint();
int width = (int) Math.ceil(paint.measureText(name));
```

it returns 0 for the first time and 111 from then onwards.

By making use of this piece of code:

```
int width = (int) Math.ceil(textView1.getTextSize());
```

it always returns 21, which is wrong way to make use of, because the function of textView1.getTextSize() is specially reserved for getting the number of characters inside of textView1 only.

- Is there any alternative way or method available to get the correct size of the text view width inside of in a list view, either in bold typeface with white background (unread messages) and normal typeface in grey background (read messages), and then align all text to the left? Please help me out.
- Getting a value of width of 195 for text view inside of in a list view is a little short of the correct value of size of 203. Does it take into fact that the text painted and measured is in normal typeface, without considering and taking into account the text in bold typeface? Does anyone over here by know of any way that it can be returned up correctly with in?
- The following functions of `textView1.getHeight()` and `textView1.getWidth()` always return 0. Is there some function similar to that of `public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus)` for any Android activity that can be used for a pop up window such that its width can be adjusted and set programmatically, after it is drawn, to be the maximum width of all the text views inside of in a list view. By making use of this following piece of code,

  ```
  view2.post(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
          windows.showAtLocation(layout,Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
      }
  });
  ```

  it did not seem to help out either, within into resolving to this very issue, very much further more.

Thank you in advance.

[See also related question over here by, too.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49776167/inflating-a-pop-up-window-parent-viewgroup)

Comment: Real size of a view is not measured yet in getView. getWidth() returns the width you assigned to, in xml or programlly. -1 and -2 for WRAP_CONTENT and MATCH_PARENT. It's normal to get a 0.

Comment: W/InputEventReceiver this warning isn't caused by you. I see it thousands times in log of various  apps.

Comment: For me, I always start a thread, sleep for 0.01 second then measure the already drawn views. It's really not a good manner but it works.